# Facebook Audience Network interstitials not showing

Tags: objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.x, facebook-audience-network

I am working on my app, which is built using Sprite Kit. I tried to add the function to load the ad, but the ad is not loading. I am not sure whether this is because my app is not live yet, and I need to turn on some sort of 'sandboxing', or whether I am doing something wrong. The point of display of the ad is called from an `SKScene`, and the ad display functions and methods (the loading, displaying, as well as the delegate) is in the parent `UIViewController`.

Below is the code for directing the app to the `ViewController` from the `SKScene`:

```
GameViewController *vc = (GameViewController*)self.view.window.rootViewController;
[vc loadInterstitial];
```

`GameViewController` is the parent view controller of the `SKScene`. Below is the code contained in the `GameViewController`:

```
- (void)loadInterstitial
{
    self.interstitialAd =
    [[FBInterstitialAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:@"Placement ID"];
    self.interstitialAd.delegate = self;
    [self.interstitialAd loadAd];
}

- (void)interstitialAdDidLoad:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    NSLog(@"Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed");

    // You can now display the full screen ad using this code:
    [interstitialAd showAdFromRootViewController:self];
}

- (void)interstitialAd:(FBInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
      didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Interstitial ad is failed to load with error: %@", error);
}
```

The method `interstitialAdDidLoad` is not being called, nor am I receiving any errors.

Comment: Hey, Did you get the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the issue of interstitial ads not showing up when I declared FBInterstitialAd instance inside loadInterstitial method. After moving the declaration outside the method, It magically worked. See the Facebook Audience network samples here: https://github.com/fbsamples/audience-network-support

Answer (score 0):

Add `FBInterstitialAdDelegate` to your `GameViewController` interface.